# Weird behaviour when saving date to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc

I need to be able to save birth date which in the app is represented as GregorianCalendar to Oracle DB as date.

That should be simple right? Wrong. Here is my problem.

When I save birth date I do it as following

```
CallableStatement cstmtData= connection.prepareCall(sql);
stmtUpdateRec.setDate(1,birthDate==null?null:new java.sql.Date(birthDate.getTime().getTime()));
```

Works perfectly well for dates after Jan 1, 1950. However any dates prior to Jan 1, 1950 are converted to the 21 century i.e. Jan 2, 1917 is saved to the database as Jan 2, 2017.

Any ideas why does this happen?

Comment: Use debug to see what you're getting from this code, this way you will know from where is the date is taken from. Also tell us how did you define your date field in the DB

Comment: I got correct date just as I expected.

Comment: show us the sql query you're trying to run

Comment: It want tell you anything as it is a PL/SQL proc from package. When I debug the proc, the date is already invalid on the first meaningful line of the PL/SQL code. This is not a mask issue...

Comment: `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` handle the number of seconds since _1970_. Are you sure the dates before 1950 are handled correctly?

Comment: I am sure that the dates were handled incorrectly and that was the problem. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for letting me bounce my thoughts off of you. I figured it out. Roey Golzarpoor you were right as the issue was with one of the SQL statements inside of my proc.

I don't know why but for whatever reason I have **uppercased** DATE field. I used actual `upper()` function on date field. That caused this absolutely wacky behaviour.

Comment: That would have caused implicit conversion to a string, and at some point implicit conversion back. The behaviour suggests your NLS_DATE_FORMAT has a two-digit year with the RR format model.